# Switch EBS volume to another instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I currently have a micro instance backed by an EBS volume. I have nginx and MySQL installed on it.
Everything is on the EBS volume.

I want to upgrade to a small instance. Both instances are configured to use Ubuntu (12.04.3 LTS and 12.04.1 LTS, 64-bit)

The following are the steps I am going to perform:

1. Stop the micro instance.
2. Detach the EBS volume and attach to the small instance as root.
3. Boot up the small instance.

Question: Will everything continue to work fine as before?

Question: The micro is currently in us-east-1c and the small is in us-east-1b. If this matters, what can I do to overcome it?

Answer **
I  figured.
This is what I did:

1. Stop the micro inst.
2. Create an AMI out of it.
3. Start a new small inst using the AMI.
4. Delete the AMI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to move your volumes. You can do this instead.

1. Stop your micro instance
2. Change your micro instance type to small
3. Start your instance

Comment: In that case, you need to create a snapshot of the volume and then create a new volume from the snapshot in the correct zone. This would be a good time to increase your volume size if you happen to need it.